# Connect to a message service bus that is running with a MassTransit and RabbitMQ dotnet service using Javascript

Tags: reactjs, rabbitmq, queue, message-queue, masstransit

I have a backend microservice that is using MassTransit and RabbitMQ to publish some messages. I am interested in implement a solution to relay those messages to my app's front end which is written in ReactJS.

I have researched online on various tutorials, most of them show me how to use a JavaScript rabbitMQ client to subscribe/connect to the service bus. But since it is wrapped in MassTransit, and the URL is in the format of "rabbitmq://...", how do I subscribe to this messaging host using Javascript? Ideally I would like to use a WebSocket connection, research tells me that I should consider either STOMP or MQTT, is that something I need to configure in my backend MassTransit/rabbitmq service?

My backend service also have some http endpoints that I can reach using a plain http/https URL, such as https://localhost:7179/api/doSomeJob. Will this help with my intention of using a WebSocket connection to subscribe to the MassTransit service bus?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/masstransit-rabbitmq -or- for WebSockets using something like SignalR (there is a sample for using that with MassTransit).

Comment: Thanks Chris! I do not need to use the cloud for that, correct? About the npm package, I didn't see any API documentation on that, can you point me out to that please?

Comment: There is no documentation, there is a sample in the GitHub repository.